# How do I make my script target multiple columns in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have the following script in Google sheet:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 3) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

I copied it from this site: https://spreadsheetpoint.com/insert-timestamps-in-google-sheets/#Keyboard_Shortcut_to_Insert_TimeStamp
But I modified it a tiny bit to fit my purpose.

Right now, my script allows me to get a date whenever the cells in column C(3) are changed, but I also want to include cells in column F(5) and I(7). How do I do that?

Comment: Do some research into the [OR operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet()
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1") { 
    if(e.range.columnStart==3 || e.range.columnStart==6 || e.range.columnStart==9) {
      e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date();
    }
  }
}
```